# jquery selector not finding elements ajax loaded to work with lightbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector, lightbox

I'm trying to get smoothdivscroll working with lightbox plugin when loading content through ajax, but my efforts were in vain so far. Thats why I'm asking you for some help on this.

Here is the link to my test page: http://cablemodem.fibertel.com.ar/gustavolauro/

And bellow the code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        });
        $("#item-100").click(function(){
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("getAjaxContent", "retratos.html", "replace");
        });
        $("#item-101").click(function(){
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("getAjaxContent", "artistico.html", "replace");
        });
        $('a[rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();   
    });
</script>
```

I'm using smoothdivscroll smoothdivscroll.com and lightbox http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

The issue is that the ajax loaded content is not working with lightbox, I believe that this is because the selector a[rel*=lightbox] cannot find the recent loaded content but I was unable to solve the issue even when I tried lots of things.

Hope you can help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run your code with opened console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Firebug is your friend - learn to love it.

Now when you ajax load, you have to make sure that you bind all of the new content as it was not on the page originally when you tried to bind the anchor tags with the lightbox

something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
                        addedAjaxContent : function(){
                           $("#makeMeScrollable").find('a[rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
                        }
            });
            $("#item-100").click(function(){
                $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("getAjaxContent", "retratos.html", "replace");

            });
            $("#item-101").click(function(){
                $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("getAjaxContent", "artistico.html", "replace");
            });
            $('a[rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();   
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hey I noticed that and deleted the extra "});" but the issue persists. i think im going mad! –

Comment: Still there on the link you posted in the original question.

Comment: Done, I've updated the last code on the question without the extra "});"

Comment: Whe you click an image on the artistico galery it should open the image on lightbox. I placed the first image on the screen only to test lightbox. The issue comes later, once you press one of the links when the content is ajax loaded to populate smoothdivcroll on the bottom of the page.

Comment: So when you click one of the images in the scrollbar you want them to appear in a lightbox?

Comment: Still the same issue. The image opens without lightbox.

Comment: I am still a little confused on what you want to do. If you want the images to appear in the scroll at the bottom, and then when you click one open in a lightbox, then you will need to wrap each of the img tags being loaded via ajax (from the html file) in a <a rel=lightbox ... just like your sample image.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want. I've my images wrapped on the "artistico" link wrapped with <a rel=lightbox>, but I don't know why it's not working. Why the images are not opening with lightbox once you click one of them.

Comment: Remove the <html><head>...</head><body> etc tags from your external html files and try again. The only thing that should be in there are the <a rel=lightbox ...><img /></a>

Comment: Done, the file only contains <a rel=lightbox ...><img /></a> formatted tags.

Comment: Ah - sorry I am unfamiliar with the smooth scroll. You will need to call the lightbox using the afterAjaxCall callback http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/callbacks.html#addedAjaxContent

Comment: Something like the above - I have never used that plugin but basically after the ajax request returns, you need to bind the lightbox to the newly loaded images links. You should have all the tools you need.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out, sorry it took me so long to get there. Wasn't thinking straight and its always harder to fix other people's code when it is not in front of you.